# Excel VBA Type Mismatch Worksheet Object

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a compile error:

> Type Mismatch

and cannot determine the source of the problem. I am sure it is something simple. The error shows when I call `CreateUniqueEmpList` with the ws objects as arguments (VBE specifically highlights the `recordsWS` argument.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim recordsWS As Worksheet
    Dim empsByJobTitles As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set recordsWS = Sheets("Student&GroupTransDetails")
    Set empsByJobTitles = Sheets("Employees")

    Call CreateUniqueEmpList(ByVal recordsWS, ByVal empsByJobTitles)

End Sub

Sub CreateUniqueEmpList(tranWS As Worksheet, empWS As Worksheet)

    empWS.Cells.Clear

    tranWS.UsedRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=empsWS.Range("A1"), unique:=True

    empWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

What I have done:

1. Commented out call to `CreateUniqueEmpList`, set a break point, and checked to make sure the worksheet object was set. It was.
2. Removed the parentheses from the method call. The whole line then looked like this: `CreateUNiqueEmpList ByVal recordsWS, ByVal empsByJobTitles`
3. Changed the way in which I `Set` both worksheet objects by using `Worksheets()` instead of `Sheets()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have it the wrong way round. Try `Sub CreateUniqueEmpList(Byval tranWS As Worksheet, Byval empWS As Worksheet)` and remove Byval from the call.

Comment: And there it is... Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot (usefully) pass a Worksheet object ByVal,  Just remove the ByVal from the call.

Comment: @TimWilliams So I did some more research and just to clarify, when I pass ByVal I essentially create a copy of the worksheet and protect the original from modifications? If I pass ByRef then a pointer is duplicated which gives me direct access to the same object in the called function/sub/method? What is the standard way to handle passing of worksheet objects and which method is the default for VBA?

Comment: You cannot pass a worksheet `ByVal` - a worksheet has to exist, and you cannot create a "throwaway" copy of it to pass to a method. The default in VBA is ByRef: if you try to pass an object `ByVal` you end up copying the *pointer*, not the object.  Chip explains it:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Comment: Great resource, it cleared up a lot for me. Thanks for the prompt responses.